# If (a, b) = 1 and $x^a = y^b$ then $x = n^b$ and $y = n^a$ for some $n$.

Tags: number-theory

> If $(a, b) = 1$ and $x^a = y^b$ prove that $x = n^b$ and $y = n^a$ for some $n$.

This is Exercise 26 from the book Analytic Number Theory by Apostel. The book has suggested two hints:

> 1- If $(a, b) = 1$ there exist $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ such that $ax - by = 1$.
>
> 2- If $(a, b) = 1$ and $(a/b)^m = n$, then $b = 1$. In addition, if $n$ is not the $m$th power of a positive integer, then $n^{1/m}$ is irrational.

It's more than 2 hours now that I am trying prove the statement, but I can't. Hint 1 doesn't help at all! Hint 2 also results $y=mx$ for some m a positive integer. Please help!

Note. $(a,b)$ is greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Hint 1, since $a,b$ are coprime we can find integers $c,d$ such that $ac-bd=1$. wlog they are both positive.

Hence $x^{ad}=y^{bd}=y^{ac-1}$, so $y=\frac{y^{ac}}{x^{ad}}$. Taking the $a$th root of both sides we get $y^{1/a}=\frac{y^c}{x^d}$. The rhs may not be in lowest terms but it is certainly rational and we could put it into lowest terms, so by Hint 2 $y$ must be $n^a$ for some integer $n$. But $x^a=y^b=n^{ab}$, so $x=n^b$.

Comment: the problem was that I was using x,y in x^a, y^b as same as x,y appears in ax−by=1. thanks a lot :))

Comment: Yes, that part of the hint was unhelpful, not to say tricky! :)